# Dynamically injecting component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple component with a button. The action handler for this button is written in component controller (.ts file) and when clicked alerts and logs.

```
<button (click)="handleClick($event)"></button>
```

in **button.component.ts**

```
handleClick($event) {
  alert('');
}
```

This component works fine if included in page directly like so :

```
<app-button></app-button>
```

Now, I am trying to inject button component dynamically inside a placeholder. I need to do this as I need to inject multiple components to a placeholder dynamically( inside a for loop).

I have gone through the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). I have also read through a lot of articles on the web. - [this](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d) , [this](https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36) and many more.

**Issue**:
I am able to inject the component successfully in the placeholder. However, when I click the button, I see that `handleClick` is not a function error. Why is the button click handler which has been defined in the button controller not being recognized.

Help me find the missing piece.

**UPDATE**: The issue was that action handlers of that component needs to be public as suggested by @CommercialSuicide in the comments. Thank you for all the answers and comments.

Comment: Can you produce your same error on stackblitz/plunker?

Comment: Did you add entrycomponent inside your declaratory?

Comment: Example on stackblitz would be great, otherwise, show more code, how you inject components and so on.

Comment: @ChellappanV: yes I did. I can see component being injected. But only the actions etc are not bound

Comment: Methods of injected component which you're calling, are they public?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide: Thank you!. This was the issue. :)

Comment: @CommercialSuicide: can you add it as an answer so that i can mark it as the accepted

Comment: @SandeepNayak, sure

Comment: @SandeepNayak, I've added the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods of injected component which you're calling, are they public? If they are private, it's expected behavior, they will not be accessible outside the component, just make them `public` and you will be able to call them from other components. You can learn more about modifiers in [DOCS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html), in *"Public, private, and protected modifiers"* section.

Answer (score 1):

in your `app-button` define:

```
@Output()
buttonClicked:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

within `app-button`, listen for click event on whatever element you need and handle it in some handler:

```
clickHnadlerInYourAppButton(){
  this.buttonClicked.emit();
}
```

make instance  of your component in parent like you do and subscribe to its `@Output()`. E.g.:

```
yourAppButtonComponentInstance.buttonClicked.subscribe(c => console.log('here is your click'));
```

don't forget to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Component HTML

```
<app-button *ngFor="let item of array(3);let i = index" [data]="i"></app-button>
```

Parent Component TS

```
export class AppComponent  {

  array(n) {

    return Array(n)

  }
}
```

Button Component HTML

```
<button (click)='handleClick($event)'>A Button</button>
```

Button Component TS

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handleClick($event) {
    alert("clicked button-"+this.data)
  }
}
```

Working example in [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjwebh)